# What's the difference between getService() and createInstance()?

Tags: xul, xpcom, xulrunner

I realized that both:

```
Components.classes["@me.org/mycomponent;1"].createInstance();
```

and

```
Components.classes["@me.org/mycomponent;1"].getService();
```

works the same way to get a xul component. So, what's the difference of using one or another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getService` will create a singleton, whereas `createInstance` creates a new instance each time you call it.  `getService` will return the same object every time.

Comment: Well, createInstance asks the factory for an instance every time. Some factories always hand out the same instance!

Comment: @Neil so both will return the same instance always? I found the nsIServiceManager.idl file, but it don't have the implementation for me to see.. I'm still looking..

Comment: I said *some* factories. If you look in nsIGenericFactory.h (or ModuleUtils.h) then you will find three #define NS_GENERIC_FACTORY_* macros which cover the most popular cases.

Comment: so, I better use getService :)